# Верификация сертификата HTTPS

Tags: java, https

Если зайти браузером на сайт по HTTPS, то будет передан сертификат браузеру, который в свою очередь проверит его в сертификационных центрах. А как обстоят дела, если на сайт обращается программа, используя предположим стандартный HttpClient? Тож будет обращение к сертификационным сервисам? Если да, где будет взят их список, через АПИ операционной системы?

Comment: [Java HttpClient с SSL](https://www.baeldung.com/java-httpclient-ssl)

Comment: Браузер это такая же программа. И в сертификационный центр конечно не ходит. Он точно так же как и другие программы либо пользуется системными сертификатами либо какими-то своими которые принёс с собой.

Comment: Тое java приложение тож пользуется системными сертификатами через какой-то АПИ? Не может же с собой принести jdk эти сертификаты